# Difference between "=" and "~>" for specifying versions in Gemfile and Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hey fellow stackerenos!

Sorry for such a basic question but what is the difference between these lines in the gemfile.lock and/or gemfile?

```
 /Gemfile.lock or /Gemfile

 mygem (1.1.0)
 yourgem (= 1.3.4)
 hisgem (<= 4.2.1)
 hergem (>= 0.5.1)
 somegem (~> 4.1.5)
```

I can figure that

```
 hisgem (<= 4.2.1)
```

means any version of this gem less than 4.2.1 should work. And similarly, hergem (>= 0.5.1) means any gem version greater than 0.5.1 should work.  But what's the difference between

```
 yourgem (= 1.3.4)
```

and

```
 somegem (~> 4.1.5)
```

Do they both specify exact versions of the gem?  How are they different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74

From that page...

> gem 'library', '~> 2.2'
>
> Notice that we only include 2 digits of the version. The operator will
>   drop the final digit of a version, then increment the remaining final
>   digit to get the upper limit version number. Therefore ‘~> 2.2’ is
>   equivalent to: [‘>= 2.2’, ‘< 3.0’]. Had we said ‘~> 2.2.0’, it would
>   have been equivalent to: [‘>= 2.2.0’, ‘< 2.3.0’]. The last digit
>   specifies the level of granularity of version control. (Remember, you
>   can alway supply an explicit upper limit if the pessimistic operator
>   is too limited for you).